# Setting cookie in codeigniter with one name and several values

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I want to set a cookie in Codeigniter whenever the user clicks on "add to my favorites". But I'm confused. Because I have to add several items with one name at the same time. You know this is not possible and the CI overrides the previous values. Look at this:

```
$this->input->set_cookie(array("name"=>'fav', 'value'=>2500, 'expire'=>100000));    
        $this->input->set_cookie(array("name"=>'fav', 'value'=>3500, 'expire'=>100000));    
        $this->input->set_cookie(array("name"=>'fav', 'value'=>4500, 'expire'=>100000));
```

And when I try to get `fav` value using this function:

```
printer($this->input->cookie("fav"));
```

I get this result:

`4500`

How should I set a cookie for user when they ad an item to their favorite list so that in the moment of retrieving them I know what to retrieve. I cannot use database because this implementation is for the users who are not registered members.

Comment: Not sure, but since you need 'several items with one name at the same time' - it seems like you need array of values in cookie. This could help, maybe: http://snipplr.com/view/43435/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $this->session->set_userdata for storing values.

```
$fav = $this->session->userdata("my_favs");// get existing list
$fav[] = $new_fav; // append new items to list
$this->session->set_userdata(array("my_favs"=>$fav)); // update session with existing one.
```

To print all items

```
 $fav = $this->session->userdata("my_favs")
foreach($fav as $fitems)
  echo $fitems."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **print_r()** instead of **printer()**.
more than that, you should use: 
    $this->input->get_cookie("fav");
Have a look here for more information: [Cookie helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

Comment: no `printer` is a custom function which prints a string with styled wrapper.